Why does Mattie agree to Rooster's ambush?
After clearing the cabin of Quincy and Moon, Rooster devises a plan to deal with the rest of Ned Pepper's gang and Tom Chaney:

                                  Mattie
       What do we do now?
  
                                  Rooster
       We wait. They ride up, what we want is to get them all in
       the dugout. I will kill the last one to go in and then we will
       have them in a barrel.
  
                                 Mattie
       You will shoot him in the back?
  
                                  Rooster
       It will give them to know our intentions is serious. Then I
       will call down and see if they will be taken alive. If they
       won't I will shoot them as they come out. I am hopeful that
       three of their party being dead will take the starch out of
       them.

                                   Mattie
        You display great poise.


Why is Mattie okay with this? it sounds like Rooster is planning to shoot all of the gang members, including potentially Tom, without explaining where that justice was coming from. Tom dying without knowing it was for the death of her father is precisely what Mattie doesn't want based on her conversation with LeBoeuf.

Which version of True Grit does this relate to?

Beg pardon, the 2010 one with Jeff Bridges.
